# Practical maximum length of a HLS manifest

Tags: http-live-streaming, hls.js

The specification for HLS doesn't seem to provide a maximum number of segments that can be placed in a HLS manifest.

If I am trying to store a 24 hour long HLS video, is it acceptable to have 8640 segments in the manifest (of 10 seconds each) or will most players cough at this?

If not, what is acceptable?

Comment: did you got answers from somewhere?  I have a requirement for 50k segments